# Copy the rules of RelativeLayout.LayoutParams before API 19

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Im trying to copy `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, and i need the new Params to be exactly like the old ones. So consider this method:

```
private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams copyParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams source){
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams copy = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)source);
    return copy;
}
```

Now, this works all right, but it will only compile above API-Level 19, as eclipse conveniently tells me.
To make this work pre-API-19, i tried this:

```
private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams copyParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams source){
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams copy = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((ViewGroup.LayoutParams)source);
    copy.setMargins(source.leftMargin, source.topMargin, source.rightMargin, source.bottomMargin);
    return copy;
}
```

By casting to ViewGroup.LayoutParams, i can force the use of the ViewGroup.LayoutParams CopyConstructor. It is readily available, but it will only copy the height and width. So i need to transfer the margins myself, which i do in line 3 of example 2. But this still leaves out the rules in the source layout, like `RelativeLayout.BELOW`, for example.

I can't find a `copyRules()` or `setRules()` method (or anything equivalent) anywhere in the docs, but i can see the `addRule()` method of `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. Considering that `source.getRules()` returns an Array i think i could loop over that and add each rule to my new LayoutParams, but that feels like im doing it wrong. Is there a sane way to copy these rules?

TL;DR: Before API 19, is there a way to copy the rules of RelativeLayout.LayoutParams wholesale, and if not, what is the least insane way to copy them at all?

Comment: My solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29664367/938427

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did to copy a `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` with all its rules:

```
@NonNull
private static RelativeLayout.LayoutParams copy(ViewGroup.LayoutParams viewLayoutParamsToCopy) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams copiedParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(viewLayoutParamsToCopy);
    if (viewLayoutParamsToCopy instanceof RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParamsToCopy = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewLayoutParamsToCopy;
        int[] rulesToCopy = relativeLayoutParamsToCopy.getRules();
        for (int verb = 0; verb < rulesToCopy.length; verb++) {
            int subject = rulesToCopy[verb];
            copiedParams.addRule(verb, subject);
        }
    }
    return copiedParams;
}
```

To make it work I had to carefully read the documentation of the `getRules()` method:

> Retrieves a complete list of all supported rules, where the index is the rule verb, and the element value is the value specified, or "false" if it was never set.

Comment: Best version i've seen yet. Accepted.

Answer (score 4):

well, if clone didn't work, probably your last resort will be a good ol' fashioned for-loop uh.

use `getRules()` to get the list of rules in the current `LayoutParams` and `addRule(int, int)` to add them to a `new` LayoutParam.

**old answer:**

In this case I would try `.clone`.

`LayoutParams` in general are very simple objects with just a few integers, so `.clone` should handle it nicely.

**original answer:**

try:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams copy = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((ViewGroup.LayoutParams)source);
```

the constructor with ViewGroup.LayoutParams exist since API 1.

ps.: Even thou I know it will compile, I strongly suggest you to double check that all the parameters were properly copied over (not just with, height n margins)

Comment: This only copies the height and width. nothing else. i have covered that in example 2 in my question. heres the docs for confirmation. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#RelativeLayout.LayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29

Comment: also, that is VERBATIM the line 2 in my example 2. -1

Comment: oh wow, don't have to be so aggressive for someone trying to help you. There's a scrollbar on line 2 and I didn't see it all. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Please excuse the capitalization, that was uncalled for. Sorry. But even clone doesn't work, since "the method clone() from the Type object is not visible". i think it means that RelativeLayout.LayoutParams does not implement the Cloneable interface, right?

Comment: yeah, i guess that will have to do then. thanks anyway, gonna change the vote to +1.

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you, man! This should be accepted as the right answer.

Comment: @androidevil - yes, it works. but it doesnt answer the question, which clearly states that i am looking for a SANE way to do this, that also copies the specific parameters for RealtiveLayout.LayoutParams like BELOW or ABOVE. As of yet, i havent found one. Anyways, thats why im not accepting the answer. i upvoted it, though.

Comment: Attempting to copy the rules: `getRules` only returns supported rule ids, so you have to call `getRule` on each one to retrieve its value, and that method is only supported in API level 23, so this does not solve the problem.