# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: android

```
TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
                LayoutParams tvLp = new LayoutParams((new LayoutParams(
                        0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f)));
                tvLp.gravity = (Gravity.BOTTOM);
                tv.setLayoutParams(tvLp);
```

When I run the above code in pre-Kitakat devices I am getting No such method error. I found this solution [Android: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200522/android-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-on-linearlayoutlayoutparams-init) in which the below code is used to avoid such error. But using the below solution, I cannot programmatically  set gravity,layout weights etc. Is there any workaround to solve this?

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)(new    LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)));
```

Comment: what is `TextView  tv` parent layout ?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot programmatically set gravity,layout weights etc", does it crash? Please be more specific

Answer (score 2):

```
LayoutParams tvLp = new LayoutParams((new LayoutParams(
                        0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f)));
```

the *copy* constructor, the one that takes a [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)) as object, was introduced with api level 19. But you can use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#LinearLayout.LayoutParams(int,%20int,%20float)), that is part of the sdk since api 1.

```
 LayoutParams tvLp = new LayoutParams(
                            0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f);
```